# Can illiberal democracy be considered a mature democracy?

Tags: democracy, political-theory

According to [this article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/dani-rodrik/illiberal-democracies-on-the-rise_b_7302374.html) illiberal democracies are becoming fashionable these days:

> PRINCETON - Nearly two decades ago, the political commentator Fareed
>   Zakaria wrote a prophetic article called “The Rise of the Illiberal
>   Democracy,” in which he worried about the rise of popular autocrats
>   with little regard for the rule of law and civil liberties.
>   Governments may be elected in free and fair elections, he wrote, and
>   yet routinely violate their citizens’ basic rights.
>
> Since Zakaria’s piece, illiberal democracies have become more the norm
>   than the exception.

According to Larry Diamond (via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy)) a democracy consists of four key elements:

> (a) A political system for choosing and replacing the government
>   through free and fair elections; (b) The active participation of the
>   people, as citizens, in politics and civic life; (c) Protection of the
>   human rights of all citizens, and (d) A rule of law, in which the laws
>   and procedures apply equally to all citizens.

On the other hand, an [illiberal democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illiberal_democracy):

> is a governing system in which, although elections take place,
>   citizens are cut off from knowledge about the activities of those who
>   exercise real power because of the lack of civil liberties.

So, according to Larry Diamond, an illiberal democracy is not a democracy (or at least this is my conclusion).

**Question:** can illiberal democratic regimes be considered democratic regimes or they, in fact, should be considered authoritarian regimes with a tendency towards dictatorship? Or shortly put, isn't "illiberal democratic" just a fancy concept for a nondemocratic regime?

To narrow down the question, I am thinking about [Hungary and its Prime Minister](http://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2015/06/hello-dictator-hungary-orban-viktor-119125), Viktor Orbán.

Comment: I believe https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/democracy is much more accurate and says nothing about civil rights or rule of law (except that everyone has the right to vote). I think you (and many others, sadly) are confusing democracy with republic.

Comment: Is seems that the difference is simply in which definitions you pick. There's no "right" answer.

Comment: @barrycarter but rights exist because they are expressed by laws. If you have no rule of law, then you have no rights since its enforcement is at the discretion of the government. For example, you may have the right to being judged, but without rule of law a cop may decide otherwise and shot you dead with total impunity...

Comment: @barrycarter - you are right about the confusion. Thanks for pointing it out. While democracy technically (from definition) does not state about civil rights, I think Larry's definition has more substance and illustrates what modern people actually expect from a working (mature as opposed to flawed) democracy nowadays. That is why I have chosen his "definition".

Comment: @SJuan76 However, if the majority in a true democracy decides that was OK, it's legal. You don't *need* rule of law for a democracy, though it's useful. You can always decide by majority vote ex post facto. Alexei: It would be interesting to do a survey, but I'm personally generally unhappy w/ the concept of definition drift, especially since the US Constitution never mentions democracy.

Comment: @barrycarter you are missing the point, without rule of law and civil rights it is very easy for a faction to intimidate voters and affect the electoral process. I will use the Godwin wildcard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_election_and_referendum,_1936

Comment: @SJuan76 OK, I've heard a variant of this argument. You're saying the majority of voters can deny the vote from a minority, and repeat the process until only very few people (perhaps as few as 2) can vote. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @barrycarter Not necessarily the majority of voters; the current government may feel that the next elections won't go the way they want; without rule of law they may just kill / jail / exile the opposition even if they do not have public approval. Government officials actions are not checked democratically one by one, there is no voting involved in the process of jailing someone. Think of military dictatorships/coup d'états

Comment: @SJuan76 The moment they kill/jail/exile the opposition without public approval, it's no longer a true democracy. You don't need a "rule of law" per se, just enough of a rule of law to maintain democracy. I guess this begs the question: what do you mean when you say "rule of law"? To me, it means in part that you can't punish someone ex post facto unless there was a law against what they did in the first place. Maybe I'm misunderstanding though.

Comment: @barrycarter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_law

Comment: Can [propagandized term] be considered a [propagandized term]? Downvoted.

Comment: I would recommend tagging this with [tag:political-theory], sincethere seems to be nothing here about actual, real governments - just some definition and whether some activities are consistent with it.

Comment: @indigochild - I have tagged it as you proposed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Based on the Given Definitions

To restate the definition from the question, something is a democracy if (and only if) it meets these four criteria:

> - (a) A political system for choosing and replacing the government    through free and fair elections;
> - (b) The active participation of the    people, as citizens, in politics and civic life;
> - (c) Protection of    the human rights of all citizens, and
> - (d) A rule of law, in which    the laws and procedures apply equally to all citizens.

We are asked whether an *illiberal democracy* is really a democracy, or something else. So what is an illiberal democracy? Given by the question,

> is a governing system in which, although elections take place, citizens are cut off from knowledge about the activities of those who exercise real power because of the lack of civil liberties.

It should be clear that this does not necessarily violate any of the four conditions to be a democracy. However, there at least two facets that are somewhat interesting:

This system is a democracy, so long as those with "real power" are not preventing it from being so. Criteria (a) *could* be violated by our hypothetical political leaders, but will not necessarily do so. This gets us back to age-old questions about the virtues of our leaders. The same goes for criterion (d) - without the citizenry knowing whether laws are being applied fairly to leaders, we don't know whether the rule of law in fact exists. However, there is no criteria in our definition that citizens know anything significant about their leaders.

Second, the idea of an illiberal democracy requires that there be a "lack of civil liberties". All four of our criteria can be met without many civil liberties, but any hypothetical example would have to satisfy what civil liberties exist in order to be interesting. For example, even without freedom of the press or free association we could have a "free and fair" election - if there is no media. However, if the media is being manipulated to prefer one candidate, party or viewpoint than the election is definitely not "fair".

**Short answer:** Yes, an illiberal democracy can be a democracy. However, it is also possible for an illiberal democracy to not be a democracy.